# select2 not using data- attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am attempting to use select2 for my dropdowns in a .Net Core web site.  I created a dropdown with:

```
<select id="buildingIds" style="height:1em;" 
  class="form-control"
  multiple 
  data-ajax--url="@Url.Action("GetLookupTableData", "Buildings")"
  data-ajax--data-type="json" 
  data-placeholder="Select one or more buildings"><option></option></select>
```

And then in my script put:

```
$('select').each(function () {
  $(this).select2();
});
```

And when I run everything, my dropdown always responds with "No results found" and the placeholder never appears.  If I change my javascript to:

```
$('select').each(function () {
  $(this).select2({ 
    ajax: {
      url: '/Buildings/GetLookupTableData',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
   });
});
```

Then everything works as expected except the placeholder still doesn't appear. I don't want to hard-code this for every select in my site.  Can anyone tell me why it's not reading the data attributes?

**Edit:**
I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but I'm using webpack to bundle my javascript.  Not sure if that could leave something vital out of select2 or not.

**Edit 2**
Per comments below stating that data-* attributes only replace existing options, I changed my javascript to:

```
$('select').each(function () {
  $(this).select2({
    placeholder: "Select some options",
    ajax: {
      url: '',
      dataType: 'json'
    }
  });
});
```

Still no joy.  The placeholder that is showing is the one from the javascript, not the one from the data-placeholder attribute and it still doesn't pull the URL from the data-ajax--url attribute.

Comment: What's the version of jQuery, because: _"Due to a jQuery bug, nested options using `data-*` attributes do not work in jQuery **1.x**."_ (https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes) ?

Comment: Using jQuery 3.2.1

Comment: What about using `placeholder` plugin property: `placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder')` ?

Comment: You can also do like this  `$(this).select2({ placeholder: "Select a state"});` right?

Comment: @A. Wolff So are you saying that the data-* attributes don't do anything unless you read them into your select config?  Because that seems contrary to  "However, you may also define your configuration options by using the HTML5 data-* attributes, which will override any options set when initializing Select2 and any defaults." from https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes

Comment: @DrewB No i'm not saying that. You are right, it should work by setting data attribute in HTML markup but it could failed if you set it in some way that it isn't parsed when initializing plugin. Now, `$(this).data('placeholder')` would failed too, `$(this).attr('data-placeholder')` could be an other option if set later after initial DOM parsing. My first comment was just because i was wondering if you have already tested it, using plugin option, not data-* attribute.

Comment: The important part seems to be: _"which will **override any options set when initializing Select2** and any defaults."_

Comment: Silly question but are you using a document ready?

Comment: @fjoe Yes I am.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There's an open [bug report](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5169) for the problem with the `ajax--url` attribute with a [proposed fix](https://github.com/NadeemAfana/select2/commit/1ba9478a77d6124329fc4ef62445e9a00ddf6b1e)

Comment: @Andreas Am I reading that correctly that the bug-fix should be out in 4.0.6 rc1?  Because that's the version I'm using.

Comment: It's planned for 4.0.6 but it's missing a review yet. I don't know if it is already in rc1. And for the placeholder -> [issue 5133: data-allow-clear and data-placeholder not working](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/5133)

Comment: The fix is not included in 4.0.6-rc1: https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/4.0.6-rc.1/src/js/select2/options.js#L81 - it's still `ajax-Url` instead of `ajax--url`

Comment: I can confirm that `data-tags="true"` does not work for me. But if I use it in the initialization call, it does.

Comment: I also tried the `placeholder` option, and I see a behavior  fully contrary to https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes#camelcase-options

Answer (score -1):

try code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).select2({
            ajax: {
                url: $(this).data('ajax--url'),
                dataType: $(this).data('ajax--data-type'),
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function(data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            placeholder: $(this).data('placeholder')
        });
    });
});
```